# How to pass more than one parameter to View from Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an ActionResult in my HomeController defined to return JSON.  The JSON is used in my View to render a jqGrid.  This works perfectly.  In addition to the JSON being returned, I need to also return other data (i.e. a decimal value that is not part of the JSON).  What are ways I can do this?  I am fairly new to MVC. Thanks for any help provided.

This is my return statement in my ActionResult:
**return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return a composite class that contains your grid data and any other data.  then you can interegate the json object on the client.

at least that's how i'd do it.

Comment: Is there another way to do this other than a composite class?  I ask because in my View I simply have a Script tag that reads the JSON to render the jqGrid.  I am not sure how I would read a composite class to extract data used in Javascript and the other value I need displayed in the view.  Are there any examples that can help me?  Thanks again...

Comment: I think if you have a class that has say two properties, that you can extract them using the property name in json.  There's some information here http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_JSON_%28_JavaScript_Object_Notation_%29 that shows you ways of getting an object and its properties.